# Unchecked casting while returning multiple generic classes

Tags: java, generics, casting, variable-assignment

In my code I'm required to keep a collection of pairs, both of them Generic type classes that hold the same generic return value (`GenericTypeA<T>` and `GenericTypeB<T>` where the T will always be the same in each pair) like so:

```
private HashMap<GenericTypeA<T>, GenericTypeB<T>> myMap;
```

Of course I'm unable to declare the map like that due to it using different Ts for some pairs, so I've used:

```
private HashMap<GenericTypeA, GenericTypeB> myMap;
```

Given an object of `GenericTypeA<T>`, my code should perform a method using T on `GenericTypeB<T>`

```
public <T> void foo(GenericTypeA<T> key, T t){
    GenericTypeB<T> value = myMap.get(key);
    value.goo(t);
}
```

I'm getting `unchecked assignment` warning in line `GenericTypeB<T> toResolve = myMap.get(key);`, casting the value into `GenericTypeB<T>` doesn't work either.
It is necessary for value to be of `GenericTypeB<T>` due to it's `goo()` method receiving `(T t)` as parameter.

Any way i can improve my code without suppressing warnings?

(using java, Intellij ide)

Comment: "so I've used" You've used raw types: use `HashMap<GenericTypeA<?>, GenericTypeB<?>>` instead.

Comment: @AndyTurner How do I later cast it into GenericTypeB < T >?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where the T will always be the same in each pair

Java's type system is not expressive enough for the compiler to be able to know that, so you have to manage this fact yourself.

Provided you enforce this constraint in your code correctly, there is nothing wrong with the unchecked cast here.

> Any way i can improve my code without suppressing warnings?

No; and suppressing warnings is not problematic per se, *provided you fully understand why the warning is there*.

Follow the advice of *Effective Java*, and comment the suppression to document *why* it is safe, e.g.:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  // Safe because I make sure the Ts of key and value match.
GenericTypeB<T> value = (GenericTypeB<T>) myMap.get(key);
```

---

Note that you have not needed the explicit cast in your code because you are using raw types. Don't: use a wildcard bound instead:

```
private HashMap<GenericTypeA<?>, GenericTypeB<?>> myMap;
```